# How to validate null fields dynamically based on different inputs

Tags: java

I want to validate POJO fields dynamically.

```
Class MyPOJO {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String filed3;
}
```

There is a list that contains field names to help me with this. for example, in method 1, field1 and field2 should not be null, so `List<String> nonNullFields` should have field1 and field2. in method 2, field3 should not be null, `nonNullfields` will only have field3.

The method will look like this:

`public boolean nullCheck(MyPojo pojo, List<String> nonNullFields)`

Comment: Have you looked into [Java Bean Validaiton](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation)?

Comment: The key here is that I need validations based on nonNullFields

Comment: Having strings containing field names is error prone, why can't you have a predicate which calls getters on the POJO? As your nullCheck method knows it is checking a MyPOJO.

Comment: But also: what specific problem are you having doing this?

Comment: please add a sample of either function `nullCheck` as code, or calling method 1,2 with desired input and return value. this question is not clear enough for users.

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like this?

```
public class MyPojo {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    
    public static boolean nullCheck(MyPojo pojo, List<String> nonNullFields) {
        return nonNullFields.stream().allMatch( field -> {
            try {
                return MyPojo.class.getDeclaredField(field).get(pojo) != null;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyPojo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```